# Understanding the TCP checksum function

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, tcp, checksum

I believe that the TCP checksum function does the following:

1. Break up the pseudoheader and the TCP segment header and data into 2 byte blocks.
2. Add a one byte padding of 0s to the end of the last block if it's not 2 bytes long, to make it 2 bytes.
3. Take the one's complement of the sum to get the TCP checksum.

Sounds simple enough. Hence I wrote my own generic `checksum` function:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

uint16_t checksum(uint16_t * data, int size) {
    uint16_t sum = 0;

    int i = 0, length = size / 2;

    while (i < length) sum += data[i++];

    if (size % 2) sum += data[i] & 0xFF00;

    return htons(~sum);
}
```

However other people have written `checksum` functions which seem to be more complicated. For example:

```
uint16_t checksum(uint16_t * addr, int len) {
    int nleft = len;
    int sum = 0;

    uint16_t * w = addr;
    uint16_t answer = 0;

    while (nleft > 1) {
        sum += *w++;
        nleft -= sizeof(uint16_t);
    }

    if (nleft == 1) {
        *(uint8_t *) (&answer) = *(uint8_t *) w;
        sum += answer;
    }

    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xFFFF);
    sum += (sum >> 16);
    answer = ~sum;
    return (answer);
}
```

I have a few questions regarding this code:

1. What does the statement `*(uint8_t *) (&answer) = *(uint8_t *) w;` actually do?
2. Why do we take the sum as:

   ```
   sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xFFFF);
   sum += (sum >> 16);
   ```
3. Did the way to calculate the TCP checksum change?

I really don't see why we do `sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xFFFF)`. Consider `sum` is `0xABCD`:

```
0xABCD >> 16    == 0x0000

0xABCD & 0xFFFF == 0xABCD

0x0000 + 0xABCD == 0xABCD
```

It seems like a redundant step. Same goes for the next statement `sum += (sum >> 16)`.

Comment: Seems like the reason for `sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xFFFF)` is for wrapping all the data into `16` bit integer, hence in your second example the `sum` is declared as `int sum = 0;`

Comment: For Question 1, it pads the last word with 8 bits of zeroes, as per RPC 793.

Comment: Note that the checksum is done in one's complement. That is different from simply wrapping around an overflowing uint16_t as your `sum += ...` would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checksum function appears to be for big-endian processors only.

The first while loop is optimized for speed.

The `&answer` trick loads the last byte (if there were an odd number of bytes) into the high byte of `answer`, leaving the low byte zero, similar to what your code does with `data[i] & 0xff00`.  The way it works is this

```
1) take the address of answer      (&answer)
2) convert that to a byte pointer  (uint8_t *)  
2a) on a big endian processor the first byte of a 16-bit quantity is the high byte
3) overwrite the high byte with the last byte of the data
```

The checksum is supposed to be computed with the carries added back in.  It's assumed here that this code is running on a machine where an `int` is 32-bits.  Therefore, `(sum & 0xffff)` is the 16-bit checksum, and `(sum >> 16)` are the carry bits (if any) that need to be added back in.  Hence, the line

```
sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);
```

adjusts the sum to include the carries.  However, that line of code could itself generate another carry bit.  So the next line `sum += (sum >> 16)` adds that carry (if any) back into the checksum.

Finally, take the ones-complement of the answer.  Note that `htons` is not used since the whole function implicitly assumes that it is running on a big endian processor.

Comment: rfc 1071 states that checksum calculation is independent of byte order.

Answer (score 2):

> What does the statement *(uint8_t *) (&answer) = *(uint8_t *) w;
>   actually do?

This casts `uint16_t` to `uint8_t`, so only **8** most-right bits are copied from `w` into `answer`. Consider:

```
uint16_t x = 0x1234;
uint16_t* w = &x; // *w = // 0001001000110100

*(uint16_t *) (&answer) = *(uint16_t *) w; // answer = 0001001000110100

*(uint8_t *) (&answer) = *(uint8_t *) w;   // answer = 0000000000110100
```

---

> Why do we take the sum as:

```
sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xFFFF);
sum += (sum >> 16);
answer = ~sum;
```

The `sum` is **32** bits. `65536 ≡ 1 mod 65535`, so the [end-around carry expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-around_carry#Ones.27_complement) `(sum & 0xffff) + (sum >> 16)` reduces `sum` modulo `65535`. This is necessary to add any (eventual) resulting carry back into the resulting sum.

Answer (score 1):

1. `*(uint8_t *) (&answer) = *(uint8_t *) w;` On the right side, it converts `w` to a `uint8_t*` and dereferences it. It truncates the garbage data that would be read when dereferencing `uint16_t*` pointing to the last byte. On the left side, it takes the address (pointer) of `answer` and converts it to `uint8_t*` and dereferences it. So it takes the first byte pointed by `w` and assigns the value to the first byte of answer. In effect, this line does the `2. Add a one byte padding of 0s to the end of the last block if it's not 2 bytes long, to make it 2 bytes.` The conversions on the left side are needed to support big endian systems... I think.

Answer (score 1):

1. This statement accommodates the case (see [RFC793](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt) or RFC1701) where the packet has an odd number of bytes: `[A,B] + [C,D] + ... + [Z,0]` by incorporating into the sum a quantity (`answer`) with the 2 most significant bytes as `Z` and the 2 least significant bytes as 0. Remember `+` here is always 1's complement addition.
2. `sum` is a 32-bit accumulator. To add in 1's complement, we add the carry back in after accumulating bits. The 2 most significant bytes of `sum` contain the carry bit(s), if any.
3. If you take a look at [RFC1701](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1071) you can see at the top which RFCs update it. There are none that supersede it.