# Error in TCP checksum calculation

Tags: c, networking, checksum, tcp

I am developing a simple IP suite for 8-bit microcontroller (ENC28J60 IC is the ethernet driver) using C. I have implemented UDP and ARP protocol successfully, but stuck with the TCP. The format of the frame is OK. (checked with wireshark) Only the TCP checksum is wrong. (IP checksum is OK)

The checksum calculator function I have made is working fine because for IP and UDP works great. So, it must be something with the header/ fields I guess or simply the coding. 
I need to know the fields associated with the checksum calculation.
I am specially confused about the "length" field in the header. in some sources i have found that the "pseudo-header" length should be counted, others said the opposite.
I am really confused about this "length". Which i did here is counting the length (in byte) of the TCP header ( IP header was excluded) and the data inside it and put it in that field.
Am I wrong?

Here is the code inside TCP packet building function:

```
char TCP_packet[1500];
uint16_t checksum_value;

//  IP header starts

TCP_packet[0]= 0x45;
TCP_packet[1]= 0x00;

data_length+=40;    

TCP_packet[2]= ((data_length>>8) & 0xFF);
TCP_packet[3] = (data_length & 0xFF);   

TCP_packet[4]=0x1A;         //  Arbitrary ID= 0x1010
TCP_packet[5]=0x30;         //
TCP_packet[6]=0x00;
TCP_packet[7]=0x00;
TCP_packet[8]=0x80;         //  Time to Live
TCP_packet[9]=0x06;         // TCP

TCP_packet[10]=0x00;        // IP checksum 10,11
TCP_packet[11]=0x00;

TCP_packet[12]=My_IP[0];
TCP_packet[13]=My_IP[1];
TCP_packet[14]=My_IP[2];
TCP_packet[15]=My_IP[3];
TCP_packet[16]=Dest_IP[0];
TCP_packet[17]=Dest_IP[1];
TCP_packet[18]=Dest_IP[2];
TCP_packet[19]=Dest_IP[3];

// Checksum update
checksum_value = checksum(TCP_packet,0,19);
TCP_packet[10]= ((checksum_value>>8) & 0xFF);       // IP checksum 10,11
TCP_packet[11]= (checksum_value & 0xFF);


//  TCP_port
TCP_packet[20]= ((source_port>>8) & 0xFF);
TCP_packet[21]= (source_port & 0xFF);

TCP_packet[22]= ((destination_port>>8) & 0xFF);
TCP_packet[23]= (destination_port & 0xFF);


//  TCP_Sequence_number
TCP_packet[24]= 0x00;
TCP_packet[25]= 0x00;
TCP_packet[26]= 0x00;
TCP_packet[27]= 0x01;


//  TCP_Ack_number
TCP_packet[28]= 0x00;
TCP_packet[29]= 0x00;
TCP_packet[30]= 0x00;
TCP_packet[31]= 0x00;


//  TCP_data_offset_and_control_bit
TCP_packet[32]= (0x05 << 4);
TCP_packet[33]= 0x01;


//  TCP_window
TCP_packet[34]= 0x05;
TCP_packet[35]= 0xDC;

//  checksum
TCP_packet[36]= 0x00;
TCP_packet[37]= 0x00;

//  TCP_pointers
TCP_packet[38]= 0x00;
TCP_packet[39]= 0x00;

for (int x = 0;x<(data_length-40);x++)
{
    TCP_packet[40+x] = raw_data[x];
}


//  Checksum part Starts

char TCP_checksum[1500];

// Pseudo header
TCP_checksum[0]=My_IP[0];
TCP_checksum[1]=My_IP[1];
TCP_checksum[2]=My_IP[2];
TCP_checksum[3]=My_IP[3];
TCP_checksum[4]=Dest_IP[0];
TCP_checksum[5]=Dest_IP[1];
TCP_checksum[6]=Dest_IP[2];
TCP_checksum[7]=Dest_IP[3];
TCP_checksum[8]=0x00;
TCP_checksum[9]=0x06;
TCP_checksum[10]= (((data_length-20)>>8)& 0xFF);
TCP_checksum[11]= ((data_length-20) & 0xFF);


//  TCP Header & Data
for (uint16_t data=20;data<data_length;data++)
{       
    TCP_checksum[12 + data -20]= TCP_packet[data];
}


//  TCP_checksum
checksum_value= checksum(TCP_checksum,0,(data_length - 8 ));            // Minus korsi milanor jonno. jani na keno always ek beshi ashe

TCP_packet[36]= ((checksum_value>>8) & 0xFF);
TCP_packet[37]= (checksum_value & 0xFF);

//  Checksum part End
bool is_OK = false;
while(is_OK==false)
{
    is_OK = ENC_Transmit(TCP_packet, data_length ,'I');
}
```

[image: Wireshark analysis]

Comment: The checksum is computed given the TCP header and payload. The way you arrange to get these fields is irrelevant, what counts is the function `checksum` **which code is missing**. Even with that the question would still be off-topic as it is a debugging request (as stated). Please, provide a  [mcve].

Comment: Maybe duplicate with [TCP Checksum calculation doesn't match with the the wireshark calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727881/tcp-checksum-calculation-doesnt-match-with-the-the-wireshark-calculation).

Comment: Actually I need to know the fields associated with the checksum calculation.
I am specially confused about the "length" field. in some sources i have found that the "pseudo-header" length should be counted, others said the opposite.
I am really confused about this "length" field. Which i did here is counting the length (in byte) of the TCP header ( IP header was excluded) and the data inside it and put it in that field.
Am I wrong?

Comment: There is an RFC for this that even includes source code. Have you read it?

Comment: No, I haven't. would you please give me the link or tell me the number?
In this morning I did some tinkering and found that the difference between the actual checksum and the one i compute is always fixed for a certain length of data. like- 
If i send 30 bytes of data, error is 0x01.
For 10 bytes, its 0x2101.
13 bytes--> 0x62.
12 bytes--> 0x2101.
8 bytes---> 6D01.
And these differences do not depend on the IP/port/ data.
So, it must be something with the data length - I think.
What do you think?